# Vue Method returns [object Promise]

Tags: vue.js, axios

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ searchWord(rawString) }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    methods: {
        searchWord(rawString) {
            const splitRawString = rawString.match(/^(\w\w\w)\d/);
            if (splitRawString) {
                // If regex found a match
                return axios
                    .get(`https://www.url.com/path/${splitRawString[1]}`)
                    .then(response => {
                        return response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(error => error);
            }
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

In the example above, I'm trying to output the result of the axios promise.

Unfortunately, the content of the `<h1>` tag is: [object Promise]

If I use `console.log(response.data)`; instead of `return response.data`, it works.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

Answer (score -1):

That's because you need to have the `.then` on the function not inside the function. What is happening is the function doesn't complete execution and moves on since you did not use a `.then` after it.
try this:

```
data: () => ({ something: null})
...
async searchWord(rawString) {
            const splitRawString = rawString.match(/^(\w\w\w)\d/);
            if (splitRawString) {
                // If regex found a match
                this.something =  await axios
                    .get(`https://www.url.com/path/${splitRawString[1]}`)

            }
        }
    }
```

Stick `something` in your template instead of the function itself.

Comment: Since `searchWord` is marked as `async` it … still returns a promise. This doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: edited my answer, call the function when the search is invoked.

Comment: @Michael I don't want to assign the response data to the Vue data function. I want the response data right here: `{{ searchWord(rawString) }}`. As you can see `searchWord` takes a parameter.

Comment: then you would have to do inline `.then` which is not a great idea...why can't you just use a property and put that inline?